# Stack Exchange API Python library

Tags: python, python-2.x, api, library, stackexchange

I wrote a package a few years ago to make my interactions with the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) more straightforward. I've maintained it over the years and used it in several scripts I've written that interact with Stack Exchange. Now my goal is to release it to [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). Before I do so though, I'd like to ensure it's a clean, well written Python library. Ultimately, it'd be nice if another developer could look at the code and easily add features or fix bugs they encounter.

Due to my development environment, this is written for Python 2.7. However, I believe it is Python 3 compatible, but I do not have such an environment set up to actually test that.

The main library:

**SEAPI.py**

```
import requests
from itertools import chain
from time import sleep

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json


class SEAPIError(Exception):
    """
    The Exception that is thrown when ever there is an API error.

    This utilizes the values returned by the API and described
    here: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/error

    Parameters
    ----------

        url : string
            The URL that was called and generated an error
        error : int
            The `error_id` returned by the API (should be an int)
        code : string
            The `description` returned by the API and is human friendly
        message : string
            The `error_name` returned by the API
    """

    def __init__(self, url, error, code, message):
        self.url = url
        self.error = error
        self.code = code
        self.message = message


class SEAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, version="2.2", **kwargs):
        """
        The object used to interact with the Stack Exchange API

        Attributes
        ----------

        name : string
            (Required): A valid `api_site_parameter` 
            (avaiable from http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) which will
            be used to connect to a particular site on the Stack Exchange
            Network.
        version : float
            (Required) The version of the API you are connecting to. The 
            default of 2.2 is the current version
        kwargs : {proxy, max_pages, page_size, key, access_token}
            proxy - A dictionary of http and https proxy locations
                Example: {'http': 'http://example.com', 
                          'https': 'https:example.com'}
                By default, this is `None`.
            max_pages - The maximium number of pages to retreive (Default: 100)
            page_size - The number of elements per page. The API limits this to
                a maximum of 100 items on all end points except `site`
            key - An API key 
            access_token - An access token associated with an application and 
                a user, to grant more permissions (such as write access)

        """
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('No Site Name provided')

        self.proxy = None
        self.max_pages = 100
        self.page_size = 100
        self._endpoint = None
        self._api_key = None
        self._name = None
        self._version = version
        self._previous_call = None
        self.key = None
        self.access_token = None
        if 'proxy' in kwargs:
            self.proxy = kwargs['proxy']
        if 'max_pages' in kwargs:
            self.max_pages = kwargs['max_pages']
        if 'page_size' in kwargs:
            self.page_size = kwargs['page_size']
        if 'key' in kwargs:
            self.key = kwargs['key']
        if 'access_token' in kwargs:
            self.access_token = kwargs['access_token']

        self._base_url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/{}/'.format(version)
        sites = self.fetch('sites', filter='!*L1*AY-85YllAr2)')
        for s in sites['items']:
            if name == s['api_site_parameter']:
                self._name = s['name']
                self._api_key = s['api_site_parameter']
                self._version = version

        if not self._name:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Site Name provided')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}> v:<{}> endpoint: {}  Last URL: {}".format(self._name, 
                                                               self._version, 
                                                               self._endpoint, 
                                                               self._previous_call)

    def fetch(self, endpoint=None, page=1, key=None, filter='default', **kwargs):
        """Returns the results of an API call.

        This is the main work horse of the class. It builds the API query 
        string and sends the request to Stack Exchange. If there are multiple 
        pages of results, and we've configured `max_pages` to be greater than 
        1, it will automatically paginate through the results and return a 
        single object.

        Returned data will appear in the `items` key of the resulting 
        dictionary.

        Parameters
        ----------

        endpoint : string
            The API end point being called. Available endpoints are listed on 
            the official API documentation: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs

            This can be as simple as `fetch('answers')`, to call the answers 
            end point

            If calling an end point that takes additional parameter, such as `id`s
            pass the ids as a list to the `ids` key: 

                `fetch('answers/{}', ids=[1,2,3])`

            This will attempt to retrieve the answers for the three listed ids.

            If no end point is passed, a `ValueError` will be raised
        page : int
            The page in the results to start at. By default, it will start on
            the first page and automatically paginate until the result set
            reached `max_pages`.
        key : string
            An API key
        filter : string
            The filter to utilize when calling an endpoint. Different filters
            will return different keys. The default is `default` and this will
            still vary depending on what the API returns as default for a 
            particular endpoint
        kwargs :
            Parameters accepted by individual endpoints. These parameters 
            *must* be named the same as described in the endpoint documentation

        Returns
        -------

        result : dictionary
            A dictionary containing wrapper data regarding the API call
            and the results of the call in the `items` key. If multiple
            pages were retreived, all of the results will appear in the
            `items` tag.

        """
        if not endpoint:
            raise ValueError('No end point provided.')

        self._endpoint = endpoint

        params = {
            "pagesize": self.page_size,
            "page": page,
            "filter": filter
        }

        if self.key:
            params['key'] = self.key
        if self.access_token:
            params['access_token'] = self.access_token

        if 'ids' in kwargs:
            ids = ';'.join(str(x) for x in kwargs['ids'])
            kwargs.pop('ids', None)
        else:
            ids = None

        params.update(kwargs)
        if self._api_key:
            params['site'] = self._api_key

        data = []
        run_cnt = 0
        backoff = 0
        total = 0
        while True:
            run_cnt += 1
            if run_cnt > self.max_pages:  # Prevents Infinate Loops
                break

            base_url = "{}{}/".format(self._base_url, endpoint)
            if ids:
                base_url += "{}".format(ids)

            try:
                response = requests.get(base_url, params=params, proxies=self.proxy)
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                raise SEAPIError(self._previous_call, str(e), str(e), str(e))

            self._previous_call = response.url
            try:
                response.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
                response = response.json()
            except ValueError as e:
                raise SEAPIError(self._previous_call, str(e), str(e), str(e))

            try:
                error = response["error_id"]
                code = response["error_name"]
                message = response["error_message"]
                raise SEAPIError(self._previous_call, error, code, message)
            except KeyError:
                pass  # This means there is no error

            if key:
                data.append(response[key])
            else:
                data.append(response)

            if len(data) < 1:
                break

            backoff = 0
            total = 0
            page = 1
            if 'backoff' in response:
                backoff = int(response['backoff'])
                sleep(backoff+1)        # Sleep an extra second to ensure no timing issues
            if 'total' in response:
                total = response['total']
            if 'has_more' in response and response['has_more']:
                params["page"] += 1
            else:
                break


        r = []
        for d in data:
            r.extend(d['items'])
        result = {'backoff': backoff,
                  'has_more': data[-1]['has_more'],
                  'page': params['page'],
                  'quota_max': data[-1]['quota_max'],
                  'quota_remaining': data[-1]['quota_remaining'],
                  'total': total,
                  'items': list(chain(r))}

        return result

    def send_data(self, endpoint=None, page=1, key=None, filter='default', **kwargs):
        """Sends data to the API.

        This call is similar to `fetch`, but *sends* data to the API instead 
        of retrieving it. 

        Returned data will appear in the `items` key of the resulting 
        dictionary.

        Sending data requires that the `access_token` is set. This is enforced
        on the API side, not within this library.

        Parameters
        ----------

        endpoint : string
            The API end point being called. Available endpoints are listed on 
            the official API documentation: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs

            This can be as simple as `fetch('answers')`, to call the answers 
            end point

            If calling an end point that takes additional parameter, such as `id`s
            pass the ids as a list to the `ids` key: 

                `fetch('answers/{}', ids=[1,2,3])`

            This will attempt to retrieve the answers for the three listed ids.

            If no end point is passed, a `ValueError` will be raised
        page : int
            The page in the results to start at. By default, it will start on
            the first page and automatically paginate until the result set
            reached `max_pages`.
        key : string
            An API key
        filter : string
            The filter to utilize when calling an endpoint. Different filters
            will return different keys. The default is `default` and this will
            still vary depending on what the API returns as default for a 
            particular endpoint
        kwargs :
            Parameters accepted by individual endpoints. These parameters 
            *must* be named the same as described in the endpoint documentation

        Returns
        -------

        result : dictionary
            A dictionary containing wrapper data regarding the API call
            and the results of the call in the `items` key. If multiple
            pages were retreived, all of the results will appear in the
            `items` tag.

        """
        if not endpoint:
            raise ValueError('No end point provided.')

        self._endpoint = endpoint

        params = {
            "pagesize": self.page_size,
            "page": page,
            "filter": filter
        }

        if self.key:
            params['key'] = self.key
        if self.access_token:
            params['access_token'] = self.access_token

        if 'ids' in kwargs:
            ids = ';'.join(str(x) for x in kwargs['ids'])
            kwargs.pop('ids', None)
        else:
            ids = None

        params.update(kwargs)
        if self._api_key:
            params['site'] = self._api_key

        data = []

        base_url = "{}{}/".format(self._base_url, endpoint)
        response = requests.post(base_url, data=params, proxies=self.proxy)
        self._previous_call = response.url
        response = response.json()

        try:
            error = response["error_id"]
            code = response["error_name"]
            message = response["error_message"]
            raise SEAPIError(self._previous_call, error, code, message)
        except KeyError:
            pass  # This means there is no error

        data.append(response)
        r = []
        for d in data:
            r.extend(d['items'])
        result = {'has_more': data[-1]['has_more'],
                  'page': params['page'],
                  'quota_max': data[-1]['quota_max'],
                  'quota_remaining': data[-1]['quota_remaining'],
                  'items': list(chain(r))}

        return result
```

The library can then be used by doing something like this:

```
from SEAPI import SEAPI
SITE = SEAPI('stackoverflow')
comments = SITE.fetch('comments')
```

This would return a short list of the most recent comments from Stack Overflow. If you wanted to return more than the default 10 items, you can do this before the `comments =` line:

```
SITE.page_size = 100
SITE.max_pages = 2
```

This would paginate through 2 pages of results, returning a maximum of 200 comments (assuming that there are at least 200 comments on Stack Overflow).

Are there improvements that I should make to this code before I release it on PyPI?

Comment: Are you aware of [py-stackexchange](http://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python) ? How will yours be better than that one? In any case, I recommend including the link to your GitHub repo.

Comment: I was not aware of that, however, looking through the repository, the one I've written seems to be a much thinner wrapper. It's the single file I have listed vs. the [several](https://github.com/lucjon/Py-StackExchange/tree/master/stackexchange) I see here. It's also only 360ish lines. Mine does require that you know the end points where as `py-stackexchange` seems to have things like `.questions` instead of my `SITE.fetch('questions')`

Comment: If you're going to release the code, do everyone a favour and test it on Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

This is a *very* long `__init__` function. Before looking any closer, I'd guess that some of this can be either abstracted away or reduced. A large function generally is bad, but particularly init should be bare bones to just do what's necessary to make an instance usable. If it does too much, then it's a red flag.

First off, you're setting default values, then checking if they're in the `kwargs` and then setting them again if they are. This is confusing and triples the lines you should have. Ternaries get a bad rap, but this is the perfect use case for them:

```
self.proxy = kwargs['proxy'] if kwargs.get('proxy') else None
self.max_pages = kwargs['max_pages'] if kwargs.get('max_pages') else 100
```

Though as [@ferada](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54571/ferada) and [@jwodder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/7295/jwodder) point out, `dict.get` can return a default value. If you give it a second parameter it will return that if the key is not found, so even simpler is to do this:

```
self.proxy = kwargs.get('proxy')
self.max_pages = kwargs.get('max_pages', 100)
```

By default `get` returns `None`, so you can just use it plainly for `proxy`. With `max_pages`, passing `100` as the second parameter means that if the key isn't found, `self.max_pages` will be set to 100.

Now for the section where you try get the proper name and key. You set `self._version` again, for no particular reason as it has not changed. You also don't call `break` when finding the correct site, even though you only need to match one result and then `__init__` is done.

I would also make your strings here constants, the filter and the base url you format with:

```
class SEAPI(object):
    BASE_URL = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/{}/'.format(version)
    FILTER = '!*L1*AY-85YllAr2)'
```

I think this pattern of doing too much extends to your other much more complicated functions. Ideally every function would have one job that it does in (relative) isolation. This makes code more readable, extendable and testable. For example `fetch` could have a lot of the opening chunk moved into a separate function called `get_params` that just returns a dictionary of parameters and use fetch just to fetch the actual results. It's even easier since you're using a class, that gets around a lot of the scope concerns that you can often have with adding functions.

This `while` pattern is bizarre:

```
    while True:
        run_cnt += 1
        if run_cnt > self.max_pages:  # Prevents Infinate Loops
            break
```

Don't you achieve the same with:

```
    while run_cnt <= self.max_pages:
```

and then adding to `run_cnt` at the *end* of the loop? Or just using `for _ in range(self.max_pages)`? I might be missing something, but if I am it should be clearly commented.

Comment: Instead of the ternaries `dict.get` also has a second parameter for the default.

Comment: @ferada: ...which defaults to `None`, so you could just write `self.proxy = kwargs.get('proxy')`.

Comment: Excellent points, I feel foolish for not saying that. Updated now.